# Keep getting "Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'" as output from json

Tags: flutter

I want to call a json api from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts, but my output is "Instance of Future".

**I obviously want the correct output to be 1. Check the link as to why it should be 1**

getJson() is in a different .dart file(but same project) as the output. 
I believe it is working correctly(since there is an output)

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

Future<List> getJson() async {
  String apiURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

  http.Response response = await http.get(apiURL);
  return json.decode(response.body);
}

Future getData(int i, String place) async {
  List _data = await getJson();

  return _data[i][place];

}
```

Then the output is

```
Text("This is the output ${getData(0, "id")}"
```

which results in 
`"Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'"`

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your `Text` inside `FutureBuilder` - something like that:

```
FutureBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasData) return Text("This is the output ${snapshot.data}");
  else return Text("There is no output yet");
}, future: getData(0, 'id'),);
```

Comment: The output text is in a `Column(children: <Widgets>[Text(""), Text("")]`  Can you explain how to do it there?

Comment: You can wrap the whole `Column` in `FutureBuilder` if you need this data for both `Text`s. If `snapshot.hasData` you return filled texts. In other case you can return what you want - some placeholder or just empty `Container`

Answer (score 0):

You need to await for the response
So instead of:

```
Text("This is the output ${getData(0, "id")}"
```

You need to do:

```
String _data = await getData(0, 'id');
Text('This is the output $_data');
```

Comment: My output is in a stateful widget like this

`class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {}`

Do I need to add something else? Because I'm writing `String _data = await getData(0, 'id');` before the override in the _MyAppState class, but getting an error for await

Comment: Yeah that is fine, you could call this in initState().
But function that awaits has to be async so for example you could do this like:

`String _data;

void showData() async {
  getData(0, 'id').then((String s){
    if(mounted){
      setState(() => _data = s);
    }
  });
}`

Or you could just use FutureBuilder like different answer suggested